# How Fake OR Mock Docusign APIs in Laravel Test cases

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

I am trying to write a test case for Docusign API, but without actually making calls to DocuSign API (don't want to make a bunch of calls to API when running test cases multiple times).
I have checked Docusign PHP SDK is not providing any fake methods. Any helpful source or code will be helpful.

Here is my Testcase code:

```
$dataSet = [
    'dealer_id' => $user->id,
    'contract_template_id' => faker()->uuid(),
];
login($this->user)
    ->put(
        route(
            'sdu.dealers.contract-template.update',
            ['dealer' => $dealer->id]
        ),
        $dataSet
    )
    ->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK)
```

Here is Docusign API call code:

```
public function validateContractTemplateId(string $contractTemplateId): bool
{
    $templatesApi = new TemplatesApi($this->apiClient);
    try {
        $templatesApi->get($this->accountId, $contractTemplateId);
    } catch (ApiException $e) {
        $errorMessage = $e->getResponseBody();
        throw  (new CustomApiException($errorMessage, $errorMessage->message, $e->getCode()));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Anyone can help me with this, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the SDK to provide you with a mocking class. Laravel intrinsically has support for [HTTP Mocking](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mocking) which you can use to simulate responses from DocuSign

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here I want to update you that I am already using Docusign Official SDK for API integration which is internally using cURL not HTTP client.